# Is data on phone memory accessible by service center?

Tags: internal-storage, files

I used Micromax phone and gave it to service center for display change. I have moved my apps to SD card and removed it.

Is it possible for them to get my chat history and media file (photos, videos) in chat app like (Viber, Line) from my phone memory that may be misused?

Comment: Theoretically, yes it is very possible for them pull your personal data. Force phone to ADB debugging, plug to PC, and next would be ingenuity. If you left the SIM card in the phone, pulling that info would be even easier. This isn't an answer because I can't back it with any reference, plus it might go against site policy.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use full device encryption with a secure password/PIN?

- No -> yes, it is possible
- Yes -> next question

Did you tell them the PIN/password or unlock the device for them?

- Yes -> yes, it is possible
- No -> It shouldn't be possible, but it will be if (a) Micromax has put a backdoor in the phone software and shared that information with their service centres; or (b) there's a security vulnerability in the phone which is not generally known but the service centre does know about. If there is a backdoor (case a), then there might as well be a remotely accessible backdoor, so you shouldn't worry about giving it to the service centre. And in case b, if there is such a vulnerability, then the service centre might have installed a backdoor, which would let them recover the files after you restore the phone, so you shouldn't worry about them recovering the files anyway.